# SQL DOB DOD Age Calculated Field

Tags: sql, .net

I have a Person table with a DOB and DOD(Date Of Death (Nullable)) fields.

I would like to add a computed column that displays the Persons age, calculated using DOB if DOD `ISNULL` or using DOD if DOD `IS NOT NULL`.

Any help would this would be great. So far i have the following but not working:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(DOD) THEN (datediff(year,[DOB],getdate())-case when 
(datepart(month,[DOB])*(32)+datepart(day,[DOB]))>(datepart(month,getdate())
*(32)+datepart(day,getdate())) then (1) else (0) end) ELSE (datediff(year,
[DOD],getdate())-case when (datepart(month,[DOD])*(32)+datepart(day,[DOD]))>
(datepart(month,getdate())*(32)+datepart(day,getdate())) then (1) else (0) end) 
END
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DATEDIFF(year,[DOB],COALESCE([DOD], GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this works. However it does not report the correct age as it is not taking months and days into account. In effect in most cases it is reporting the persons age +1. Any clues on how to correct this?